# on efficiently separating one data file into two files for model building work

Tags: python, pandas

There is a data file, consisting of 100K rows, where each row stores a data point. I would like to randomly select 10K rows and save them into a validation file; and use the remaining rows to be saved into a training file. In stead of writing a code to do this, are there any existing function in `scikit-learn`, `pandas` or in generic Python to efficiently separate a data file into two ones?

Comment: Does [train_test_split](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) do what you like to achieve?

Answer (score -1):

There can be only one reason not to use sklearn train-test-split method because you probably don’t want to take the labels out from the features. You just simply want to split the DataFrame in two sections without splitting the features and labels.

If you don’t want to use train-test-split from sklearn, you can do it in pandas too

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 2))

In [12]: msk = np.random.rand(len(df)) < 0.8

In [13]: train = df[msk]

In [14]: test = df[~msk]
```

Comment: There's no restriction in train_test_split to have separate features and labels. You can also provide a single array in it to split.